Calculate I1,Iv,the voltage Ug2 for a source voltage of Ug1=5V,the voltage UR2 = URs as a function of Ug2 in case of a balanced bridge
Bridge circuit used in experimental set-up with values. Ri is the internal resistance of the LIA,
R1 and R2 are fixed high precision resistances, Rv is the decade resistance and Rs is the sample
resistance

Looks pretty straight forward with  10k/(50+10k). what's the problem?  The bridge looks like (10k+10k) || (10k+10k) = 10k
